# Java Concurrency in practice “Listing 12.5. Producer-consumer test program for BoundedBuffer.” cyclic barrier await understanding?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am reading Java Concurrency in Practice and encounter the following code snippet.
Listing 12.5 https://jcip.net/listings/PutTakeTest.java

```
// Listing 12.5. Producer-consumer test program for BoundedBuffer.
package net.jcip.examples;

import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

/**
 * PutTakeTest
 * <p/>
 * Producer-consumer test program for BoundedBuffer
 *
 * @author Brian Goetz and Tim Peierls
 */
public class PutTakeTest extends TestCase {
    protected static final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    protected CyclicBarrier barrier;
    protected final SemaphoreBoundedBuffer<Integer> bb;
    protected final int nTrials, nPairs;
    protected final AtomicInteger putSum = new AtomicInteger(0);
    protected final AtomicInteger takeSum = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new PutTakeTest(10, 10, 100000).test(); // sample parameters
        pool.shutdown();
    }

    public PutTakeTest(int capacity, int npairs, int ntrials) {
        this.bb = new SemaphoreBoundedBuffer<Integer>(capacity);
        this.nTrials = ntrials;
        this.nPairs = npairs;
        this.barrier = new CyclicBarrier(npairs * 2 + 1);
    }

    void test() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < nPairs; i++) {
                pool.execute(new Producer());
                pool.execute(new Consumer());
            }
            barrier.await(); // wait for all threads to be ready
            barrier.await(); // wait for all threads to finish
            assertEquals(putSum.get(), takeSum.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    static int xorShift(int y) {
        y ^= (y << 6);
        y ^= (y >>> 21);
        y ^= (y << 7);
        return y;
    }

    class Producer implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                int seed = (this.hashCode() ^ (int) System.nanoTime());
                int sum = 0;
                barrier.await();
                for (int i = nTrials; i > 0; --i) {
                    bb.put(seed);
                    sum += seed;
                    seed = xorShift(seed);
                }
                putSum.getAndAdd(sum);
                barrier.await();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    class Consumer implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                barrier.await();
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = nTrials; i > 0; --i) {
                    sum += bb.take();
                }
                takeSum.getAndAdd(sum);
                barrier.await();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am finding it hard to understand how cyclic barrier is invoked in main or runnable thread second time. As per my understanding, Cyclic barrier will block the thread until await is invoked on all the threads and the barrier count matches the value passed in constructor. When the barrier is awaited first time on threads, the await count in cyclic barrier will be half of desired value of (npairs * 2 + 1). How is the control executing the put sum and take sum calculation in producer and consumers, and consecutive execution on main thread?

Apologies in advance if this question sounds naive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thread starts `npairs` producers and `npairs` consumers before calling `await` on a barrier. Each if producers and consumers calls `await` so together with a main thread it allows all threads to go through barrier.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I am confused on code snippet in class Consumer. If the barrier await() is invoked on first line in run method , how is the barrier invoked second time in same method. When does the consumer thread become active to invoke the barrier await second time in run method?

public void run() {
            try {
                barrier.await();
                int sum = 0;
                //calculate sum logic
                barrier.await();   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                }
        }

Comment: When all threads arrive at first `await` they all proceed through the barrier and star doing subsequent work. Then they arrive to the second `await`, when all threads are there they proceed through it and calculate final results.

Comment: Is the cylic barrier reset back to count of number of threads, when the first await is invoked on all the threads and the threads start computing the sum?

Comment: Yes, I think that is mentioned in Java Concyrrency in practice as well

Comment: Thank you so much! I somehow missed the cyclic barrier resets itself.